# Perl HTML::parser error; Undefined subroutine &main::1

Tags: perl, html-parsing

I am getting the error

```
Undefined subroutine &main::1 called at /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0/HTML/Parser.pm line 102.
```

Here is my code

```
#open (IN,  "<", "foo.html") or die "can't open source file: $!";

my $p = HTML::Parser->new( api_version => 3,
            start_h => [&start, "tagname, attr, text"],
            text_h  => [&text,  "text"],
            default_h   => [sub { print OUT shift }, "text"],
        );
$p->utf8_mode;
$p->empty_element_tags;
$p->ignore_elements(qw(br));

$p->parse_file("foo.html") or die "parsing failed: $!";
#while (<IN>) {
#    $p->parse($_) || die "parsing failed: $!";
#}
#$p->eof;
#close IN;
```

As you can see in the commented out parts I have also tried directly opening and calling parse (with equally little luck).

The file does open fine.

Parser.pm line 102 which is error mentions is the parse_file subroutine, specifically the line calling ->parse

I have no clue where parse is, it is not in HTML::Parser nor did I find it in HTML::Entities the only dependency HTML::Parser has. =/  I am afraid I am lost at this point, the deepest magics of PERL are still a mystery to me.

Comment: Are you using `use strict; use warnings;`?

Comment: fwiw, method `parse` is apparently an XS routine (i.e. it's implemented in C)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `\&start` and `\&text`:

```
my $p = HTML::Parser->new( api_version => 3,
        start_h => [\&start, "tagname, attr, text"],
        text_h  => [\&text,  "text"],
        default_h   => [sub { print OUT shift }, "text"],
    );
```

Otherwise you are passing the result of calling `start()` and `text()`, not references to them as subs.

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation it says you should use `\&start`. If you exclude the backslash, it will be using the return value from the function `start` instead (which will be using the `@_` as argument list, as per normal subroutine calling pragma using the `&`). This value could be `1`.

Here is an example:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "$c=\&s; sub s { print 'yada' }; $c->();"
yada
C:\perl>perl -we "$c=&s; sub s { print 'yada' }; $c->();"
Undefined subroutine &main::1 called at -e line 1.
yada
```

Not sure why the error turns up there, but you might change it, see if it helps.

Oh, also, it does seem like you are not using `use strict`. When using strict, I get a much more helpful error:

```
C:\perl>perl -we "use strict; my $c=&s; sub s { print 'a' }; $c->();"
Can't use string ("1") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use at -e line
```

Comment: Thank you, referencing the sub worked!  Strict was in use =/ but this whole thing has been so strange that I'm just glad it's working now.

Comment: @Nick Johnson: strict is lexically scoped; apparently HTML/Parser.pm is not using it

Comment: @ysth Strangely enough, HTML/Parser.pm is using strict.

Comment: @TLP @ysth But the call-back is being made from C, not perl (`parse` is an XS routine), so it is understandable if the stricture is not being observed.